# Parsing Error when importing OpenZeppelin's ERC721Full.sol Library

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, nft

When I try to compile my smart contract using truffle, it comes up with this error:
Error parsing @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol: ParsedContract.sol:51:72: ParserError: Expected '{' but got reserved keyword 'override'.

My Smart Contract:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract Color is ERC721 {}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I know that this is not a new question, but I haven't found a stack overflow or other forum solution that has worked for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is that int the `ERC721` contract there is a `constructor(string memory, string memory)` function which accepts two parameters, the first is the NFT token name and the second is the NFT token symbol. 
When you are inheriting the `ERC721` contract in your `color` contract you have to define a `constructor` function which to trigger the `constructor` of the `ERC721` contract.
In nutshell you should modify your contract as follows:

```
  contract Color is ERC721 { 
    constructor(string memory name, string memory symbol) ERC721(name, symbol) { }
  }
```

or if you want to have pre-set name and symbol you can do this:

```
  contract Color is ERC721 { 
    constructor()  ERC721("Name", "Symbol") { }
  }
```

## Edit

Make your file's code as follows:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract MyCollectible is ERC721 {
    constructor() ERC721("MyCollectible", "MCO") {
    }
}
```

Also be sure that you have run `npm install @openzeppelin/contracts`

Comment: I made those changes but I’m still running into the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I had this same issue recently. For me, the issue was that my compiler was running an old version of Solidity. Once I changed my compiler's version to the latest, this error was resolved.

At the top of the file for which I was getting the error, I had:
`pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;`

My compiler was using version 0.5.1. To fix it, I changed my compiler settings to use version  0.8.12.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the contract you're importing is written for solidity 0.8 and up. You won't be able to use an older version. Simply change your first line to:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.0;
```

And it will be fixed. You can see that the imported contract is using 0.8.0.